# vb.net load datatable to datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datatable

I use the following code to generate a data table from datagridview

```
 Dim t1 As New DataTable
 For Each col As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridView1.Columns
        t1.Columns.Add(col.HeaderText)
    Next

    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        Dim dRow1 As DataRow = t1.NewRow
                  For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
            dRow1(cell.ColumnIndex) = cell.Value
        Next
    Next
```

Now the question is how do i load this datatable to another datagridview ?

Comment: hi, define datatable  and set datagridview's datasource to that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Dim table As New DataTable
    ' Create four typed columns in the DataTable.
    table.Columns.Add("Dosage", GetType(Integer))
    table.Columns.Add("Drug", GetType(String))
    table.Columns.Add("Patient", GetType(String))
    table.Columns.Add("Date", GetType(DateTime))
    ' Add five rows with those columns filled in the DataTable.
    table.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin", "David", DateTime.Now)
    table.Rows.Add(50, "Enebrel", "Sam", DateTime.Now)
    table.Rows.Add(10, "Hydralazine", "Christoff", DateTime.Now)
    table.Rows.Add(21, "Combivent", "Janet", DateTime.Now)
    table.Rows.Add(100, "Dilantin", "Melanie", DateTime.Now)


    DataGridView1.DataSource = table


    DataGridView2.DataSource = table
```

if you change or add rows in one datagrid  it changed in other one. or if you change in code and add rows you see the changes on datagrids.

**Update1:**

if you want to get data from datagrid1 and show only that data in datagrid2 use :

```
Dim table1 As New DataTable
table1 = table.Copy()
DataGridView2.DataSource = table1
```

Comment: This is exactly what i did but it wasnt loading because there was a problem in the code..thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need also

```
GridView1.DataBind()
```

and

```
GridView2.DataBind()
```

at the end